# How to write logic for using two adjacent values in the column in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If you see below

[image]

I am having a column called event. In that particular event, I need to calculate the time on how many minutes practice is stopped due to rain.

We have rain and practice strings in adjacent. How to develop a single line condition using both values in single statement ( if rain_started and practice stopped then 'stopped' ) or ( if rain stopped and practice started as 'started'). If a classify them as start and stopped .I can get that particular session time

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

Using your logic, consider the query below. It uses [LAG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) to get the previous value.

Take note that you might have different values and positioning for field `event` so just replace it with your actual values.

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select 'rain started' as event, current_time() as time_stmp,
  union all select 'practice stopped' as event, time_add(current_time(), interval 1 minute) as time_stmp,
  union all select 'rain stopped' as event, time_add(current_time(), interval 10 minute) as time_stmp,
  union all select 'practice started' as event, time_add(current_time(), interval 11 minute) as time_stmp,
),

-- ######
-- query above is just to generate sample data
-- ######

get_prev as (
  select event,
  time_stmp,
  lag(event) over (order by time_stmp) as prev_event,
from sample_data
)

select 
  event,
  time_stmp,
  case 
    when prev_event = 'rain started' and event = 'practice stopped' then 'stopped'
    when prev_event = 'rain stopped' and event = 'practice started' then 'started'
    else null
  end as status,
from get_prev
```

Output:

[image]